# Does AWS API Gateway Support Basic Authorization?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, http-authentication

Is there a way to use Basic authentication rather than AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 authentication with the AWS API Gateway Service? I need to support a system that only supports webhook calls with Basic Authentication.

Comment: When you say AWS API, are you referring to AWS API Gateway or AWS services such as S3?

Comment: Sorry, I meant AWS API Gateway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to modify the 401 Unauthorized response template so that it contains the `WWW-Authenticate` header set to `'Basic'`. Apart from that, you'll need to create a custom authorizer that verifies that the provided credentials are correct. You can find more info [here](https://medium.com/p/http-basic-auth-with-api-gateway-and-serverless-5ae14ad0a270)

Comment: Note: the linked resource has one bug in its authorizer code. On line 2, you'll need to change `event.headers.Authorization` to `event.headers.authorization` (lowercase).

Comment: This isn't a bug. He sets 'Authorization' with an uppercase 'A' under the identity sources when creating the authorizer in API-Gateway.

Comment: In fact, it is a bug.  While they do use the uppercase when configuring the route (in accordance with the spec[0]), the ApiGateway or Lambda infrastructure lowercases the header for delivery in the event (in accordance with http/2[1]).

[0] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#field.authorization
[1] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2

Answer (score 2):

You can configure an API Gateway to support Basic auth, and API Gateway supports integrations with any AWS service.

Setting up Basic auth in API Gateway requires a few steps. Check this post and search down to BobK@AWS response: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=799091&tstart=0